# How to discard an element from a set without rearranging it?

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of strings and want to remove ' ' if it exists in the list so I converted it into a set and did this

```
input=set(input)
input.discard('')
input=list(input)
```

I am able to discard ' ' if it exists but my set(and list) is being rearranged.can this be prevented?

p.s:- input is my list, i am a beginner in python.

Comment: Sets are not ordered.  You cannot rely on the elements of a set having any particular order.

Comment: Sets also discard duplicate elements. Do you want to remove duplicates as well as ''?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks people, but what i needed was

```
filter(None, some_list)
```

found it

Comment: This is the fastest one I've tested. It's rather Pythonic too!

Comment: That's weird. I always thought the first argument of filter had to be a function.

Comment: Good to know, though. Do note that this would also filter 0, None, and false from a list.

Answer (score 2):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', 'd']
>>> lst = [x for x in lst if x != '']
>>> lst
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using functional programming concepts:

```
>>> my_list = ['hello', 'there', '', 'I', 'try', '', 'to', 'be', 'helpful']
>>> my_list = filter(lambda a: a != '', my_list)
>>> my_list
['hello', 'there', 'I', 'try', 'to', 'be', 'helpful']
```

I was interested in the variety of answers, so I ran some comparisons.

```
import time

num_trials = 1000000
my_list = ['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', 'd']
start = time.time()
for i in xrange(num_trials):
    [x for x in my_list if x != '']
end = time.time()
list_comp = (end - start) / num_trials

start = time.time()
for i in xrange(num_trials):
    filter(lambda a: a != '', ['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', 'd'])
end = time.time()
functional = (end - start) / num_trials

print "Over {0} trials...".format(num_trials)
print "Using list comprehension, the average time to execute was {0}".format(list_comp)
print "Using filter and lambda, the average time to execute was {0}".format(functional)

#Over 1000000 trials...
#Using list comprehension, the average time to execute was 2.03965497017e-06
#Using filter and lambda, the average time to execute was 3.60413718224e-06
```

So it appears that list comprehension is slightly faster, at least for the list that I tested.

**EDIT:** My apologies! The list comprehension was using the preallocated list `my_list`, whereas I was making the lambda+filter expression allocate memory for a new list every time! I also included a test for the author's accepted answer, `filter(None, my_list)`. That code looks like:

```
start = time.time()
for i in xrange(num_trials):
        filter(None, my_list)
end = time.time()
filter_none = (end - start) / num_trials
```

And the new output is:

```
#Over 1000000 trials...
#Using list comprehension, the average time to execute was 1.80612707138e-06
#Using filter and lambda, the average time to execute was 2.1211681366e-06
#Using filter(None), the average time to execute was 1.11886692047e-06
```

So, it appears that `filter(None, some_list)` takes the cake!

Comment: there's a _timeit_ model that provides a convenient wrapper for execution time measurements. And yes, list comprehension is faster

Comment: I was trying to use the timeit module, but I was getting execution times of 2-3 seconds per list comprehension! Should I be using `timeit.timeit("expression_to_be_evaluated")`?

Comment: timeit gives you overall time for a huge number of iteration. On Ubuntu's iPython (maybe other Linux flavors too) there's a magical operator __%timeit__, which gives you pure per-loop result. and yes, it is __timeit.timeit__ - but I haven't used it for a while. Though it is more precise form (explicit initialization, etc...)

Comment: To be consistent - try the comprehension as __[x for x in my_list if x]__, because this is the way your solution with __filter__ works. Besides - _lambda_ is known to add overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Converting a list into a set does not preserve the order:

```
list(set([3, 2, 1]))
```

yields

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Filter your list with a [for comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead:

```
list = [elem for elem in list if n != unwantedElem]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Set** operation should not be used in this cases. Set operation will make your list elements unique. i.e if you have two or more same string repeated multiple times, then the duplicate strings will be removed. List comprehension should be used here. That will preserve the older

```
>>> a = ['apple', 'orange', '', 'grapes', 'pineapple', '', 'cherry', '']
>>> [ x for x in a if x != '' ] 
['apple', 'orange', 'grapes', 'pineapple', 'cherry']
```